# python subprocess getting error when trying to install requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, subprocess, fastapi

I am trying to develop an automate python scripts using python subprocess. I am using fastapi uvicorn server for build automatically djago project but got internal 500 server error fast api while installing requirements.txt for django project. I am using python 3.11 my code

```
@app.post("/webhook")
async def webhook(request: Request):
    try:
        
     repo_directory = 'D:/web development/ScratchFb'
     python_directory = 'D:/web development/ScratchFb/fbscratch/backendfb'
     nextjs_directory = 'D:/web development/ScratchFb/fbscratch/fontendfb'
     #clone git  repo
     clone_command = subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', 'https://github_url'], cwd=repo_directory,check=True)

     # create virtual environment python
     vertual_venv = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', 'venv', 'venv'], cwd=python_directory ,check=True)
     # Activate the virtual environment based on the platform
     if sys.platform == 'win32':
        activate_venv = subprocess.run(['venv\\Scripts\\activate'], cwd=python_directory , shell=True, check=True)
     else:
        activate_venv = subprocess.run(['source', 'venv/bin/activate'], cwd=python_directory, shell=True, check=True)

     #installing requirements.txt
     install_req_txt =  subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'], cwd=python_directory,check=True)
 
     #install npm
     npm_i =  subprocess.run(['npm', 'i'], cwd=nextjs_directory,check=True)

     # Check the exit code of npm_i before proceeding to npm_build
     if npm_i.returncode == 0:
        # Run build command if npm install was successful
        npm_build = subprocess.run(['npm', 'run', 'build'], cwd=nextjs_directory, check=True)
     else:
        print("Error: npm install failed.")
```

here error

```
{
  "error": "Command '['pip', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1."
}
```

Comment: Your `subprocess.run ... activate` will not actually create a venv environment that sticks around to the "pip install" call, meaning you're attempting to run pip install in whatever environment this script is running in, which is failing.

Comment: @Anon Coward   I am not understanding  can u please tell me what to do for fix this error?

Comment: @boyenec can you try the command in debug mode or just run it locally and add the error traceback to your question?